# Angular routes doesnt change

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a problem loading a component inside another component. It just doesn't show , but in browser the route changes , but my component doesn't update...

So i have:

```
--homepage
--coins--
       --coinspreview  <-- i cannot access this component;
--services
```

**app-component.html**

```
<app-homepage>
</app-homepage>
```

**app-homepage.html**

```
<section id="home">
  <div class="bg">
    <img class="my-bg" src="/assets/images/bg.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="container middle">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <div class="hero">
       <h4 class="hero-title">
         Top 100 Cryptocurrency
       </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

<section id="coins">
<app-coins></app-coins>

//here it shows my another component
</section>
```

**app-coins.html**

```
 <div class="container">
          <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6" *ngFor="let coin of coins$ | async">
              <div class="main" [routerLink]="['./coins/coins-preview']">
              <img class="mini" src="{{coin.image}}" alt="{{coin.name}}" />
              <div class="name">{{coin.name}}</div>

              <div class="prices">
                <p class="coin-price">
                 Pret actual: {{coin.current_price}}
                </p>
                <p class="coin-market-cap">
                  Capitalizare: {{coin.market_cap}}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And this are all my routes inside app-routing-module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'homepage',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'homepage',
    component: HomepageComponent
  },
  {
    path: "coins",
    component: CoinsComponent,
    children: [
             {
               path: "coins/coins-preview",
               component: CoinsPreviewComponent
             }
             ]
  }
];
```

I don't know what to do else.. Im so stuck but I cannot understand why It doesnt load ????

Comment: I think you don't need to add full path in children array, just the relative path to the parent path.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the child route dont repeat the parent route name.  That should make it working

Comment: No.. My guess is that the coin-preview is inside app-homepage -> inside app-coin and it somehow cant show off because of these..

Comment: You can correct the child route name and then also add router-outlet in the coin component to render coin preview

Comment: And in the routerlink domt add dot in front of route and as you are using property binding it should be in array form with each route separate ['parent','child]